# Is there a way to dis/enable assertions inline?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, assertions

Can you tell me if there's a way to dis- and enable junit.framework.Assert commands inline to ignore them?

Code example just to show what i mean:

```
junitOff(); // first method I need help with
assertTrue(false); //would normally cause an AssertionError
junitOn(); // second method I need help with
System.out.println("Broke through asserTrue without Error")
```

I know it would be possible to use try/catch but that's not what I'm looking for because I can not go on with execution in the line after the assert...

Comment: The opening command is called `/*` the closing one `*/` - strange naming convention but oh well..

Comment: Sorry guys- i tried to improve the code example including naming conventions of course!

Comment: Can you use [java assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html) instead? this can be switched on/off by using the -ea parameter.

Comment: unfortunately that's not possible.. i got a large project, no chance to change

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us, what you would like to achieve in the end.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with `try... catch` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any way to do this.  Looking at the junit code you see:

```
static public void assertTrue(String message, boolean condition) {
    if (!condition)
        fail(message);
}
```

And `fail()` is:

```
static public void fail(String message) {
    throw new AssertionError(message == null ? "" : message);
}
```

I see no ways to turn on a switch or otherwise disable it from throwing an `AssertionError`.

For the record, if you are talking about the `assert` Java primitive then that can be disabled but only at compile-time with the `-ea` switch.